# Expressions of $\sin \frac{A}{2}$ and $\cos \frac{A}{2}$ in terms of $\sin A$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to understand the interpretation of **$\sin \frac{A}{2}$** and **$\cos \frac{A}{2}$** in terms of  **$\sin A$** from my book, here is how it is given :

We have $ \bigl( \sin \frac{A}{2} + \cos \frac{A}{2} \bigr)^{2} = 1 + \sin A $ and $ \bigl( \sin \frac{A}{2} - \cos \frac{A}{2} \bigr)^{2} = 1 - \sin A $

By adding and subtracting we have $ 2 \cdot \sin \frac{A}{2} = \pm \sqrt{  1 + \sin A } \pm \sqrt{  1 - \sin A } $ ---- (1) and $ 2 \cdot \cos \frac{A}{2} = \mp \sqrt{  1 + \sin A } \mp \sqrt{  1 - \sin A } $ ---(2)

I have understood upto this far well,

Now they have broke the them into quadrants :

**In 1st quadrant :**

$$ 2 \cdot \sin \frac{A}{2} =  \sqrt{  1 + \sin A } - \sqrt{  1 - \sin A } $$
$$ 2 \cdot \cos \frac{A}{2} =  \sqrt{  1 + \sin A } + \sqrt{  1 - \sin A } $$

**In 2nd quadrant :**

$$ 2 \cdot \sin \frac{A}{2} =  \sqrt{  1 + \sin A } + \sqrt{  1 - \sin A } $$
$$ 2 \cdot \cos \frac{A}{2} =  \sqrt{  1 + \sin A } - \sqrt{  1 - \sin A } $$

**In 3rd quadrant :**

$$ 2 \cdot \sin \frac{A}{2} =  \sqrt{  1 + \sin A } - \sqrt{  1 - \sin A } $$
$$ 2 \cdot \cos \frac{A}{2} =  \sqrt{  1 + \sin A } + \sqrt{  1 - \sin A } $$

**In 4th quadrant :**

$$ 2 \cdot \sin \frac{A}{2} =  - \sqrt{  1 + \sin A } - \sqrt{  1 - \sin A } $$
$$ 2 \cdot \cos \frac{A}{2} =   - \sqrt{  1 + \sin A } + \sqrt{  1 - \sin A } $$

Now, In knew the ALL-SINE-TAN-COSINE rule but still I am not able to figure out how the respective signs are computed in these (above) cases.

Comment: Do you mean that A is in the given quadrant, or that A/2 is in the given quadrant?

Comment: They didn't provided any of such information, but I guess it's should be A/2.

Comment: It is possible to derive the following double identity that has no sign ambiguity: $\tan \dfrac{A}{2}=\dfrac{\sin A}{1+\cos A}=\dfrac{1-\cos A}{\sin A}$

Comment: Américo Tavares:This is interesting, I knew this formula before but never thought this way, thanks really appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way of computing the signs is to make them match; we know that sin x > 0 if 0 < x < π and that cos x > 0 if -π/2 < x < π/2.  Knowing whether sin A is greater than 0 or less than zero tells you whether $\sqrt{1-\mathrm{sin} A}$ is greater or less than $\sqrt{1+\mathrm{sin} A}$; that in turn lets you figure out what the overall sign on all of the right-hand terms is, and each quadrant corresponds to one of the four positive/negative pairs on the right-hand terms.

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$\cos A=\cos \left(2\cdot\frac{A}{2}\right) = \cos^2{\frac{A}{2}}-\sin^2{\frac{A}{2}}$$
and
$$1 = \cos^2{\frac{A}{2}}+\sin^2{\frac{A}{2}}.$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
1+\cos A & = \cos^2{\frac{A}{2}}-\sin^2{\frac{A}{2}} + \cos^2{\frac{A}{2}}+\sin^2{\frac{A}{2}} \\
 & = 2\cos^2{\frac{A}{2}} \\
 \Rightarrow \frac{1+\cos A}{2} & = \cos^2{\frac{A}{2}} \\
 \Rightarrow \cos\frac{A}{2} & = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos A}{2}}.
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
1-\cos A & = \cos^2{\frac{A}{2}}+\sin^2{\frac{A}{2}} - \cos^2{\frac{A}{2}}+\sin^2{\frac{A}{2}} \\
 & = 2\sin^2{\frac{A}{2}} \\
 \Rightarrow \frac{1-\cos A}{2} & = \sin^2{\frac{A}{2}} \\
 \Rightarrow \sin\frac{A}{2} & = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos A}{2}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Sure... Try $A=3\pi$ for example.